# Уведомления Windows на Unity

Tags: unity3d

Как в юнити реализовать уведомления для Windows? Мне это очень нужно

Comment: Конкретизируйте

Comment: Есть проект юнити и он должен отправлять уведомления на рабочий стол Windows 10

Comment: `Unity3D` тут вообще не причем. `Ok Google: c# windows notification`. [DocsC#](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast)

Comment: @Yaroslav Unity на платформе Mono, и стардартные библиотеки по типу System.windows.forms не поддерживается

Comment: @Mr.AntonDer и добавить нужные библиотеки не возможно?